# Change of Variable - Is this correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

I am trying to integrate this function...

$$\int_0^{\tau } \frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1-\lambda  e^{-x} (x+1)\right)^2} \, dx$$

When this integral is numerically evaluated when $\lambda = 0.1$, $\tau = 1.0$, the value is 0.766676

To find a closed form, I am using the change of variable technique.

So, here I let

$$u=1-\lambda  e^{-x} (x+1),$$

then

$$d u = \lambda  (e^{-x} (x+1)-\lambda  e^{-x})d x$$

and

$$x = -W\left(\frac{u-1}{\lambda e  }\right)-1$$.

Plugging everything back in, I get

$$I = \int_0^{\tau } \frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1-\lambda  e^{-x} (x+1)\right)^2} \, dx $$

$$= \int_{1 - \lambda]}^{1-\lambda  e^{-\tau } (\tau +1) }\frac{e^{-\left(-W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)-1\right)}}{u^2 \left(\lambda  e^{-\left(-W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)-1\right)} \left(\left(-W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)-1\right)+1\right)-\lambda  e^{-\left(-W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)-1\right)}\right)}du$$

$$= \int_{1 - \lambda]}^{1-\lambda  e^{-\tau } (\tau +1) }\frac{e^{W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)+1}}{u^2 \left(-\lambda  e^{W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)+1}-u+1\right)} du$$

where the bounds of integration are:

$$lb = 1-\lambda$$
$$ub = 1-\lambda  e^{-\tau } (\tau +1)$$

The problem is that when I numerically evaluate this function with the same parameters as above, I do not get the same results.

So, something must be wrong.

Appreciate the feedback...

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$I=\int\frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1-\lambda  e^{-x} (x+1)\right)^2} \, dx$$ and using, as you did, $$u=1-\lambda  e^{-x} (x+1)$$ then $$x=-1-W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)\implies dx=-\frac{W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)}{(u-1) \left(1+W\left(\frac{u-1}{e
   \lambda }\right)\right)}\,du$$ makes $$I=-\frac 1 \lambda\int \frac{du}{  u^2 \left(1+W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Denominator of the last equality must be $u^2 (-\lambda^2  e^{W\left(\frac{u-1}{e \lambda }\right)+1} -u +1)$. Substitution of $dx$ in terms of $du$ is where the problem arised, check it again.

Comment: Hmm...I tried that...something is still wrong...